# How to delay a javascript function

Tags: javascript

I use this code and it works so that when i reload the page the button is autoclicked but i want to make a delay so that it will be clicked after 60 seconds from page reloading

```
window.onload = function () {
  var button = document.getElementById('clickButton');
  button.form.submit();
};
```

Comment: [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Answer (score 3):

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    var button = document.getElementById('clickButton');
    button.form.submit();
  }, 60000); 
}
```

Use setTimeout() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean? What was the behavior? Any error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

To delay a page to execute some function use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) takes in most cases *two arguments* *the first* is the function to be excuted after such a amount of time given by *the second argument* in *ms*

```js
setTimeout(
function(){
 var button = document.getElementById('clickButton'); 
button.form.submit(); 
}
, 60*1000);//60 * 1000 = 60000ms = 60s
```

Comment: `setTimeout` accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: yes but in most cases we use two, in his case, but we could also use Additional arguments which are passed through to the function specified by function.

Comment: If i have a button on my page how to make this button disappears for a while and auto be clicked after whis while so that the user can watch ads after that the button will be autoclicked

Comment: You could hide it using CSS property like `button.style.visibility='hidden'; `